# Pythonic way to loop through DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, dataframe

For a non-decreasing `id` there are debit and credit transactions in the dataframe `df`. The transactions are random but ensure that at any point account is not in net debit, i.e., at any row *cumulative debit amount <= cumulative credit amount*. what is the most efficient algo to deduct each debit entry from credit entries such that credit entries with lowest 'id' get exhausted to zero before debiting from subsequent credit entries.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,3,4,4,5], 'type':['CREDIT','DEBIT','DEBIT','DEBIT','CREDIT','DEBIT','DEBIT' ], 'amount':[10.0,1.0,4.0,2.0,15.0,4.0,1.0]})
df
   id    type  amount
0   1  CREDIT    10.0
1   1   DEBIT     1.0
2   2   DEBIT     4.0
3   3   DEBIT     2.0
4   4  CREDIT    15.0
5   4   DEBIT     4.0
6   5   DEBIT     1.0
```

Desired output for this is:

```
   id    type  amount
0   1  CREDIT     0.0  # This is 10.0 - 1.0 - 4.0 - 2.0 -(4.0-1.0)
4   4  CREDIT    13.0  # This is 15.0 - (4.0 - (4.0-1.0)) - 1.0
```

Comment: What would the desired output be if the dataframe was something like:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,3], 'type':['CREDIT','DEBIT','CREDIT','DEBIT'], 'amount':[10,7,10,7]})`

Comment: @foneyoscar it would be 
`( id, type, amount)
(1, CREDIT, 0.0)
(2, CREDIT, 6.0)` as given by the sample code below.

Answer (score 1):

This is my non-pythonic solution. I am not sure if it's the best algorithm in terms of time and space complexity though (esp. when `df` grows big).

```
import numpy as np
df_deb = df[df['type'] == 'DEBIT']
df_cred = df[df['type'] == 'CREDIT']
if (not df_deb.empty):
    df_deb.loc[:, 'cum_debit'] = df_deb['amount'].cumsum()
    for idx, row in df_cred.iterrows():
        if np.nanmax(df_deb['cum_debit']) >= row['amount']:
            df_deb.loc[:, 'cum_debit'] = (df_deb['cum_debit'] - row['amount']).clip(lower=0.0)
            df_cred.loc[df_cred.index == idx, 'amount'] = 0.0
        else:
            df_cred.loc[df_cred.index == idx, 'amount'] = row['amount'] - np.nanmax(df_deb['cum_debit'])
            break
df_cred # Required output.

   id    type  amount
0   1  CREDIT     0.0
4   4  CREDIT    13.0
```